# How to design dependent dropdown menus

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing, human-interface-guideline

I am designing a profile creation screen which allows the user to add a birthday (optional). If they add a birthday, there is an additional dependent dropdown that allows them to set a reminder for predetermined amount of time before the day  (i.e. day of, 1 day before, 1 week before, etc.) I am having trouble with designing the dropdown so that users can know the alert is connected to the birthday and is also dependent on that form. I do not want to hide the alert form, as I want the users to know it's an option before having to enter their birthday. Here is what I currently have

[image]

I personally feel unclear about the reminder dropdown being greyed out, but still aligned with the birthday selection. Should I indent the reminder option to make it clear it's related to the birthday? Is there any way I could use spacing to indicate they're related? Or is there any other way I can do this without hiding the feature? If this design is fine, please tell me the reasons as to why it works, because to me I feel that there is no proper hierarchy in the design since everything is properly aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proximity, and therefore association**, can be improved by bringing the birthday reminder up alongside the date:

[image: reminder proximity]

With improved association the "Birthday Reminder" label becomes redundant.

Also, no need to disable the Reminder control. The default and visible option, "Never", clearly explains what to expect and makes it easy to skip if not needed without examining the other options.

Answer (score 0):

##### Try using to **progressive disclosure** to reveal the reminder *when* they enter the birthday option.

Since the birthday is optional, having the extra 'reminder' control is unnecessary (and potentially confusing) if they won't fill out the control on which it's dependent upon.

Why not take advantage of interaction flow and time, revealing the element *only* once the user has chosen to enter a birthday? This will reveal the relationship between the birthday and the reminder:

[image]

##### Updated option: What if it's important to surface the feature?

@bloodyKnuckles brings up a fair point about hinting at a feature in order to encourage its use.

In that case, I'm still holding off the complete interaction *until* they enter the birthday field. My thoughts are that seeing a disabled, negative state (like the 'Never' dropdown) cause more friction, that a checkbox 'opt-in' that enables for possible completion once the birthday is entered.

[image]
I'm not sure about your use case, but I used a checkbox control to allow them to opt-in. It does mean it's another click for the user, but it allows them to feel like they're giving explicit permission in this case.

Comment: A potential problem with progressive disclosure in this case is—if the only reason someone might decide to enter a birthday is to have the benefit of the reminder, then PD is hiding the fact the benefit is available. So here, possibly, the reminder informs people why the birthday is there and why they may wish to enter it.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles fair point. Another option (if the reminder is important), is to use the same disclosure, but to enable (but not autocheck) the checkbox once they've entered the birthday.